# buildbot using msysGit causing intermittent datastreram error

Tags: git, msysgit, samba, buildbot

We are using buildbot to run continuous integration. The built-in Git build step generates this command line:
`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.EXE fetch -t file:///s:/Repositories/repo +master`

s: is a samba share on a debian server mapped on the buildbot slave.

It fails intermittently (once in ~50 builds) with this error:

```
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 26936: inflate returned -3
fatal: index-pack failed
fatal: write error: Invalid argument
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this and how we can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The aleatory nature of this issue leads potentially to external causes, like hardware one (disk or memory corruption).
See [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/msysgit/2010-05/msg00035.html) for instance. They try [a all process](http://osdir.com/ml/msysgit/2010-05/msg00036.html) to re-clone correctly the bad repo, but that was for an old git 1.5, so it may not be accurate anymore.
I leave the process here just for information.

> Apparently, the easiest way to get a correct clone is to:

1/ initialize a new, empty repository,
2/ add the 'origin' remote thusly: `git remote add -f origin http://repo.or.cz/r/msysgit.git`
3/ in spite of the error, continue by fetching the pack manually:

```
(cd .git/objects/pack/ && curl -O \

http://repo.or.cz/r/msysgit.git/objects/pack/pack-5b51af9cb1b1122d27ddd53d40a8c3e4472ae9e4.pack)
```

4/ adding the non-corrupted objects using the attached bundle:
`git bundle unbundle borked.bundle`.
5/ Now fetch from 'origin' again (to update the refs correctly):`git fetch origin`
6/ Manually (!!!) remove the borked temporary object files:

```
find .git -name \*.temp -exec rm {} \;
```

7/ Now, 'git gc'

> If you already have a (borked) checkout, you might be able to get away with 4, 6 and 7.